# post the data using curl for expedia booking onsite

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I am posting one request through one api for onsite booking.
When I am posting the data through one form action and submit that I will get the response.
But when I am trying to post same url through the curl to get the response I am not getting any data .

The url is :-

```
https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?
minorRev=99
&cid=55505
&sig=1893d9f7e3e9fbd3f8a36f43cd61287d
&apiKey=1bn8n4or4tjajq23fe4l6m18lp
&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
&customerIpAddress=223.30.152.118
&customerSessionId=e80df6de9008af772cfb48a389465415
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&xml=<HotelRoomReservationRequest>
<hotelId>106347</hotelId>
<arrivalDate>10/30/2015</arrivalDate>
<departureDate>11/1/2015</departureDate>
<supplierType>E</supplierType>
<rateKey>469e1aff-49de-4944-a64d-25d96ccde3aa</rateKey>
<rateCode>200706716</rateCode>
<roomTypeCode>200127420</roomTypeCode>
<chargeableRate>252.00</chargeableRate>
<RoomGroup>
    <Room>
        <numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>
        <numberOfChildren>2</numberOfChildren>
        <childAges>3,7</childAges>
        <firstName>test</firstName>
        <lastName>test</lastName>
        <smokingPreference>NS</smokingPreference>
        <bedTypeId>23</bedTypeId>
    </Room>
</RoomGroup>
<ReservationInfo>
    <email>test@travelnow.com</email>
    <firstName>test</firstName>
    <lastName>test</lastName>
    <homePhone>2145370159</homePhone>
    <workPhone>2145370159</workPhone>
    <creditCardType>CA</creditCardType>
    <creditCardNumber>5401999999999999</creditCardNumber>
    <creditCardExpirationMonth>04</creditCardExpirationMonth>
    <creditCardExpirationYear>2017</creditCardExpirationYear>
    <creditCardIdentifier>123</creditCardIdentifier>
</ReservationInfo>
<AddressInfo>
    <address1>travelnow</address1>
    <city>Seattle</city>
    <stateProvinceCode>WA</stateProvinceCode>
    <countryCode>US</countryCode>
    <postalCode>98117</postalCode>
</AddressInfo>
</HotelRoomReservationRequest>
```

I am using that code

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
        $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
        $header[] = "Content-length: 0";


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Please help me how i can post this data through curl to get the response.I am using this in wordpress for payment booking.

Comment: What print_r($result); is ouputing ?

Comment: it will not give any output it has shown a blank array

Comment: I don't see any vars/values being posted. `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);` is an example where `$fields_string` would be something like "var1=val1&var2=val2"

Comment: Also see answer from eCaroth at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916819/php-curl-manually-setting-the-content-length-header for the content length header. I don't think you want 0 as your value.

Comment: Close your connection after `curl_exec()`

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing from the comments I posted:

- If you're trying to send data    to the curl url, you need to use
  `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`
- For header    `Content-length` the 0 value may
  be an issue
- To see if you are actually connecting to the URL (for
  example do you need to pass a    username, password for
  authentication) you may want to echo out the    returned headers with
  `CURLOPT_HEADER`
- Your URL seems to be a GET Request with name/value pairs, but you are calling curl as a `POST`
- A really good reference is at PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: can you give me any sample code that will help me lot i have tried with all this things

Comment: @DipanjanChakraborty I am not familiar with the web service you are using (expedia).  Do they want a POST request or a GET request?  If they want a POST request, what is the main endpoint URL?  I can give some sample settings in next comment.

Comment: Here's a sample...`$postVars = array('user'=>'Alex', 'occupation'=>'guitarist', 'band'=>'Rush');` Then, to assemble those vars and values into your "POST" body, you can do...`$postData = http_build_query($postVars);`  Then... you will want to give that info to your setopt` and u can do that with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);` Try that also turn on the curl option to get the output headers in the response. It may help with seeing other issues. You do that with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`

Comment: the above comment would POST the value "Alex" for field "user", and etc.